Spring hanging on a spinning Disk
I have already asked a question on the Math stack-exchange.
You can find it under the following link:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4876146/
I felt like the question is better suited for this stack-exchange because of its Physical inheritance. But now to the question:
I want to add a spring to the rope the weight is hanging on.
The Lagrangian as used in the answer to the linked question looks like this:
$$
L(p,\lambda, t) = \frac 12m\|\dot p\|^2-m g p\cdot\hat k+\lambda(\|p-q\|^2-l^2).
$$
For the rope being a spring I must add: $$F_s = k \cdot b$$ where $b$ is the constant factor characteristic of the spring and $k$ is the downwards pointing coordinate.
Would I simply add this to the potential energy part of the Lagrangian?
So the potential energy part would look like this?
$$
m \cdot g\cdot p + k \cdot b
$$
And would it be possible to make a simular simulation to this one, just with a spring?


Question is supposed to explain symbols it uses. Also, why are you using physicist's notation on the math site, and mathematician's notation here?

To formulate a Lagrangian, first identify coordinates that determine configuration of the system. Then express kinetic energy and potential energy using these coordinates and their derivatives. For the spring you need another coordinate $s$, e.g. for length of the spring. Potential energy in the spring is $\frac{1}{2}k(s-s_0)^2$ where $s_0$ is natural length of the spring.

It sounds like you want to do something that conserves energy, using Hooke's law for a spring.  The word "damping" usually indicates something non-conservative that removes energy from the system.  Which did you mean?

@JánLalinský Sorry for the notations. I thought the symblos would explain themselves form the linked Question and its answer. To your second comment, I would need to add the natural lenght s. Would that be the lenght of the spring, which could be compared with the lenght L?

I don't understand your question. Configuration of the system (position of everything in some coordinate system) depends on length of the spring $s$ and length of the thread and angles. So express kinetic energy and potential energy in terms of lengths and angles and their derivatives.

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

I) with out spring
The position vector to the mass point m is:
\begin{align*}
 &\b R=\b r+\b L=\begin{bmatrix}
                   0 \\
                   -r \\
                   0 \\
                 \end{bmatrix}+
L\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
  -\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
  -\sin(\phi) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
rotate about the z axes  with $~\omega=~$ constant
\begin{align*}
  \b R\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}
                \cos(\omega\,t) & -\sin(\omega\,t) & 0 \\
                \sin(\omega\,t)& \cos(\omega\,t) & 0 \\
                0 & 0 & 1 \\
              \end{bmatrix}\,\b R
\end{align*}
in this case you have two generalized  coordinates $~\theta~,\phi~$
II) with  spring
The position vector to the mass point m is:
\begin{align*}
 &\b R=\b r+\b L=\begin{bmatrix}
                   0 \\
                   -r \\
                   0 \\
                 \end{bmatrix}+
\underbrace{(L_0+s)\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
  -\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
  -\sin(\phi) \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\b R_s}
\end{align*}
rotate about the z axes  with $~\omega=~$ constant
\begin{align*}
  \b R\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}
                \cos(\omega\,t) & -\sin(\omega\,t) & 0 \\
                \sin(\omega\,t)& \cos(\omega\,t) & 0 \\
                0 & 0 & 1 \\
              \end{bmatrix}\,\b R
\end{align*}
where $~L_0~$ is the spring length an $~t=0~$
in this case you have three  generalized  coordinates $~\theta~,\phi~$ and the spring deflection $~s~$
the kinetic energy is:
$~T=\frac{m}{2}\b v\cdot\,\b v~,\b v=\b{\dot{R}}~$
the potential energy is:
\begin{align*}
 & U=-m\,g\,(\b R)_z+
 \frac k2\,(s^2)\,\left(\begin{bmatrix}
                \cos(\omega\,t) & -\sin(\omega\,t) & 0 \\
                \sin(\omega\,t)& \cos(\omega\,t) & 0 \\
                0 & 0 & 1 \\
              \end{bmatrix}
\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
  -\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
  -\sin(\phi) \\
\end{bmatrix} \right)_z =m\,g\,s\,\sin(\phi)-\frac k2\,s^2\,\sin(\phi)            
\end{align*}

adding a damper
to add a damper parallel to the spring , just extend the potential energy $~U~$ to $~U+F_d\,s~$,where $~F_d~$ is the damper force.  generate the equations of motion with Euler Langrange and then substitute $~F_d=b\,\dot s~$
Numeric simulation with damper
data
$~[\omega=2/15\,\pi ,g=10,m=5,r= 0.3,L=1,k=50,b=3]~$

Animation with Spring and damper

Animation without  Spring and damper 

Thanks for the answer, but I want to keep it in the coordinates from the question. I know it sounds silly, because the formula gets more complicated.

I don’t think it is good approach.

If you have a spring, you can’t use those equations, because the constraint equation doesn’t valid anymore

Oh right, I forgot about that

One more question, the coordinate system you have now chosen is the  spherical coordinate system right ?

this is correct

Are you sure that the derivative of R is the kinetic energy? What about the movement in the other axis diretions. Correct me if I am wrong, but I am new to spherical coordinates

I don't really get how I could further compute the lagrangian. Because I would have to put it in an euler lagrangian to get compute the equation and solve it numerically to see the movement Result

\begin{align*}
&R=R(\phi~,\theta~,t)\
&v=\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{\partial
R}{\partial\phi}\dot{\phi}+\frac{\partial R}{\partial\theta}\dot{\theta}+\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}
\end{align*}

But doe that include the ring movement of the Spring?

And what about the kinetic erngy, how do you sum it up to fit into a formula
